# Converting PowerPoint slides as Images of Gallery in Android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, powerpoint, android-gallery

I want the user to be able to choose a .PPT file in Android and have the app go through each slide and set each slide as an image of the gallery component. I am using the Apache POI Library to go through the powerpoint. Also to bypass the use of JRE Library in Android since many of the POI classes require it, I imported the src classes from this repo: https://github.com/qhm123/POI-Android and this way I don't use Java's built in JRE Classes. Here is what I have so far but the program is not working, I don't really know if it helps. My sample ppt is the "Sickle Cell Anemia.ppt". What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

```
package com.example.deskirassistant;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import net.pbdavey.awt.Graphics2D;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;

import and.awt.BufferedImage;
import and.awt.Color;
import and.awt.Dimension;
import and.awt.ImageIO;
import and.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import and.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public XSLFSlide[] slide;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);

        try {
            ppt2png();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void ppt2png() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("Sickle Cell Anemia.ppt");
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
        is.close();

        double zoom = 2; // magnify it by 2
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToScale(zoom, zoom);

        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();

        slide = ppt.getSlides();
        for (int i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int)Math.ceil(pgsize.width*zoom), (int)Math.ceil(pgsize.height*zoom), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
            graphics.setTransform(at);

            graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
            graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
            slide[i].draw(graphics, null, null, i);

        }

}

}
```

Comment: A shrug report - `but the program is not working`????            http://foldoc.org/shrug+report

Comment: I mean the application runs fine but I don't see it doing what I want

Comment: did you found your ans? @VineetShah